# 50A Split Phase to Single Phase Panels in RV

Tags: electrical

I want to wire up an inverter to my RV to feed a few outlets and the microwave. Due to no space for a sub panel I'm thinking of replacing the 50A split phase breaker panel with two BlueSea Systems sub panels, each running 120v.

My question is this, since the RV shore power is a 50A service which is US 240v split phase and the upstream breakers are dual pole can I split the two phases into separate panels? Is there a safety concern if one of these sub panel breakers interrupt and the other phase of the 240v is still active coming into the RV?

Nothing in my RV uses 240v so there would be no devices tied to both breaker panels at the same time.

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: I'm thinking about this more, I can keep the RV breaker panel, just put the inverter in line with L1. There really isn't a need to replace the panel and use sub panels. This appears to be what other RV owners are doing. But I'll leave my question here for possible safety concerns since it's not a straight shot from the upstream breaker to the sub panel, there's now in inverter in line with one of the legs.

Comment: I agree.  Also, no need for a transfer switch, since the shore power is a 14-50P anyway, you can just have the generator output come out on a 14-50R, and do a loopback plug.  This the 14-50 is your interlock.

Comment: I take it you only have space for a single inverter?  Also, how much room do you have for your breaker box installation, and how many circuits are you trying to pull from this thing?

Comment: The transfer switch is already there since my RV came with the generator. I could put in another inverter but there really isn't a need at least now. At most I run the microwave and charge laptops when we're camping. In the winter I'll run a space heater and that's why I'd want to separate the sources that would run off inverter. Also, Victron won't work with 2 inverters paralleled when I'm running on generator because the generator is single phase. Apparently Victron will not enable the second inverter if running them as a split phase system but the inputs between the units are in phase.

Comment: 4 circuits would run from the inverter. The outlets, microwave and one AC. I have yet to test but Victron has "power assist" so I can supplement higher power devices. My plan is if I'm visiting someone I can use their 15A outlet, set the max input of the inverter to 13A and supplement the other 2 to 3A needed for the AC so I don't blow their breaker in the house. That's the plan at least, I have yet to do the math to see how long my batteries might last, etc.

Comment: I don't see why you need 100A in an RV. Spend that money on upgrading the DC system to BlueSea if it's still fuses, and get a Goal-0.

Comment: You would need to have a new sub at the poc to split and protect the individual inverters if you want to meet code.

Comment: @Mazura a Goal-0 is just "batteries + inverter + charger" crammed into a box with wheels at *stupendous* packaging/bundling cost.  In a space-limited environment like an RV, I would want those *as separates* -  for cost, ease of fitment, customizability and unit exchange ($300 inverter not $2000 box). also your battery $ will go a lot farther buying raw batteries.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - We're talking about RVs and BlueSea systems, cost shouldn't be a concern ;) - ridiculously expensive yes. Nice to charge your phone when the power's out in your house though. I just gutted an Argosy with every bell and whistle, so now I'm a bit jaded.

Comment: @Mazura well, that is a point lol.